# Extracting probability from BERT next sentence prediction embeddings

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm using BERT's next sentence prediction module (`BertForNextSentencePrediction`) and am trying to get the probability that sentence B follows sentence A. However, the numbers BERT outputs are almost always very close to 1 (or else very close to 0), seeming to indicate some sort of boolean logic. How can I get BERT to instead output the *probability* that B follows A?

My current code is as follows, and is based on some articles that were about using BERT for next-sentence-prediction probability.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForNextSentencePrediction
from torch.nn import functional as F

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
nsp_model = BertForNextSentencePrediction.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

def next_sentence_prediction(sentence_1, sentence_2):
  encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(sentence_1, sentence_2, return_tensors='pt')
  outputs = nsp_model(**encoding)[0]
  softmax = F.softmax(outputs, dim = 1)
  print(softmax[0][0].item())
```

This does not give me the probability I'm looking for. For example, "I might go to the store today." and "Do you like butter on your toast?" gives a score of 0.9999562501907349, when in actuality I feel like the probability for this pair of sentences should be very low. On the other end of the spectrum, "I might go to the store today." and ""The man coughed." gives the almost negligible number of 4.5933375076856464e-05, when in actuality the probability should be low, but not non-existent.

Any ideas for how to extract the probability of B following A using BERT?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code as follow:

```
outputs = nsp_model(**encoding)[0]
  logits = outputs[:, 0]  
  probs = torch.softmax(logits, dim=0)  
  return probs[0].item()
```

By adding  `logits = outputs[:, 0]` You are indexing the outputs tensor. We then apply softmax to obtain probabilities, and return the probability that B follows A

Comment: The last line of your code results in `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 1` when it tries to access `probs[1]`. Aside from that, `probs` is just a one-dimensional tensor containing the number `1`, which is just the sort of boolean "probability" I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Just edited the code 
Try again, it should work

Comment: Yes, it runs.

No, it doesn't answer my original question, which is, how can I get the actual probability that B follows A, instead of some sort of boolean logic that B could follow A? Your code gives me `1.0` when I input "I might go to the store today."
and "The man coughed.", which is not useful for what I have in mind. Is there a way to actually access a probability here, or does BERT's next-sentence-prediction not have that capability? If it doesn't, how is it coming up with this boolean "probability" in the first place?

Comment: 1.0 it means the model is  very confident that sentence B does not follow sentence A. This is because the model has been trained on large amounts of text and has learned that sentences about going to the store and sentences about a man coughing are not likely to be next to each other in natural language

Comment: Then how do you account for "I might go to the store today." and "I haven't decided yet." also getting a score of `1.0`?

Comment: You are using BertForNextSentencePrediction so it is statistical model which its output based on probabilities. As an example, "I might go to the store today." and "I haven't decided yet.", the model may be outputting a probability of 1.0 because it has learned that the two sentences are commonly found together in text. The model may have picked up on patterns in the training data

Comment: 1.0 isn't a probability - it's simply impossible that those two sentences have a 100% chance to follow each other. Ultimately, my question is - *can* BertForNextSentencePrediction provide an actual *probability* that two sentences follow each other and, if so, how can this be done? Because what I have right now is not a true probability.

Comment: That is actually true @TheGoldenPatrik1